# GCC built out ELF64 binary but cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: gcc

I met strange issues about ELF32/ELF64 format in my building machine.
Both applications and kernle module don't work.

**For applications** (such as `helloworld` program), it can be built out to `ELF64` but run failed.

**For kernel modules** it will always be built out to `ELF32` format even if append `-march=x86-64` to `CFLGAS`, which leads to `Module has invalid ELF structures` issue when insmoding.

If append `-m64` and it will lead to `cc1: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set`

I guess when the first question fixed, the next will also be fixed, so I only post the first one here.

Ubunt 18.04,  gcc 7.5.0 , x86_64 PC

GCC built out `helloworld` program to ELF64 binary but cannot run

```
gcc -o hello -v -c  hello.c
...
chmod +x hello
./hello
-bash: ./hello: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

**uname -a**

```
Linux AELAB146 5.4.0-74-generic #83~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 11 16:01:00 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**gcc -v**

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
```

Kernel Module's Makefile

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS    += -Wall (and others blablabla) -m64 
KERNEL_BUILD ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

pcie_objs := common/init.o common/pcie.o common/net.o platform.o
obj-m := pcie.o

pcie.o: $(pcie_objs)
    ld -r $^ -o $@

all:
    make -C $(KERNEL_BUILD) M=$(PWD) V=1 modules
```

I'v no idea about why it's so long for the gcc Configured options in my system.

Comment: When building the kernel module, what `gcc` command exactly is `make` running?

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to pass `-c` to GCC when building an executable. It means to compile and not link, but programs need to be linked to be ran. The fact that you had to do `chmod +x hello` should have been a clue that you were doing something very wrong. Run `gcc -o hello -v hello.c` and then `./hello`.

I assume your issue with kernel modules is similarly caused by an incorrect command line, but since you didn't post the command line you used for it, I can't see where you went wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes, I made a very basic wrong at `helloworld` compile command.

Comment: For the kernel modules, I posted the Makefile and build command. When append `-m64` to `CFLAGS` it shows another issue : `cc1: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set`